# c# not catch process exit event

Tags: c#, events, process, event-handling

```
var process=Process.Start("c:\temp.txt);
process..Exited+=OnExitHandler;
```

First line open c:\temp.txt on  notepad 
But when I close this notepad I not catch OnExitHandler

why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set true 'EnableRaisingEvents'

```
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

Comment: ok, thanks! why it not default true when I add event exited?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I think we need to ask it to Microsoft :)